# Weird C# Math calculation

Tags: c#, math

below code is weird. when i debug it, i can see both "result" and "round" are 5, but output is "false". Any idea?

```
double result = Math.Log (243, 3);   // 5
double round = Math.Round (result);  // 5
Console.WriteLine (result == round);
```

Comment: What if you use decimals?

Comment: Your `result` will be `4.9999999999999991` not `5`.

Comment: I don't know where are you looking but result == 4.9999999999999991

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparison of floating point with equality operator could have loss of precision while rounding values. You can fix this by compare a difference with *epsilon*. Use a `Tolerance` like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Abs(result - round) < 0.0000001); // True
```

Comment: You can as well provide rounding fration `double round = Math.Round(result,15); `